# Tag badges have an ugly black rectangle in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, tag-badges, dark-mode

I noticed today that tag badges looked different than before in dark mode, in two places:

1. In the "Top tags" section on the user profile page, there's a black rectangle surrounding the badge class icon:

   [image: tag badges have a black rectangle in "Top tags"]
2. On the post notice of a duplicate question closed by someone with a gold badge:
   <sup>(I don't remember exactly how it looked before but it was better. This is probably subjective though)</sup>

   [image: Gold tag badge on a post notice]

Have there been intentional changes to the design of tag badges recently? Can we revert back to how it was before (at least the one in the "Top tags" section)?

Comment: There have been a few noticeable style glitches this past week with some surfacing [on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). I guess these are transitory and part of the ongoing SE style refactoring.

Comment: I find 1 to be annoying, but 2 to be fine. What bothered me most was that in 1, the medal isn't centered on the top row.

Comment: Here's [a thread on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359630) with further elaboration focused on the Badges sections and the change of style itself.